# JPQL and entity data

Tags: java, orm, entity, jpql, entitymanager

I have entity Student with two fields: id, name
I save it in the base using entityManager persist()
next, using JPQL I update one entity and get it.
Data in the entity is old. Why?
but in the DB all data of entity is changing.

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EntityManagerFactory myFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myPerName777");
        EntityManager entityManager = myFactory.createEntityManager();

        EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
        transaction.begin();

        entityManager.persist(new Student("max"));
        entityManager.persist(new Student("max"));
        entityManager.persist(new Student("max"));

        entityManager.persist(new Student("mike"));
        entityManager.persist(new Student("mike"));

        transaction.commit();

        transaction.begin();
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery("UPDATE Student s set s.userrname='JOHN' where s.id=1");
        query.executeUpdate();
        transaction.commit();

        Student student = entityManager.find(Student.class,1);
        System.out.println(student.getUserrname());

        entityManager.close();
        myFactory.close();
    }
}
```

This code return Max, but in the DB date is changing.
How can I return actual data?

Comment: I used entityManager.refresh(student);  and returned actual data, but why??
JPQL work with Entity, executeUpdate must refresh Entity too, not only db but and entity

Answer (score 0):

With `executeUpdate` you execute a SQL statement (modifying directly the DB) but do not change the Entity loaded/managed by Hibernate, hence you hold stale data in your application.

The best approach is to always work with the Hibernate entities which are managed by Hibernate and kept in the first-level cache. Your data stays in synch with the DB.

If you really need to run a statement (for example because it is a complex statement or performs much better) you need to evict the Entity and reload it again from the DB.